# CSS: Force div to overlap contents below it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to mimic an audio editor with HTML and CSS. Audio editors often have a playhead which overlaps all of the tracks below it. I am having difficulty recreating a playhead, as I cannot work out how to force it to overlap all the tracks.

The snippet below is my current setup. Although it looks fine as long as it's not scrolled down, if the document is scrolled down, the playhead does not overlap the tracks below it.

I am trying to force the `#playhead` div to overlap all of the `.track` divs.

I do not want to use `position: fixed`, as this means if the document is scrolled to the right, the playhead does not stay in the correct position.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```css
#playhead {
 background-color: white;
 height: 100vh;
 left: 64px;
 position: relative;
 width: 2px;
}

#playlist {
 width: 1024px;
}

#timeline {
 background-color: green;
 height: 16px;
}

.track {
 background-color: black;
 border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
 height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div id="playlist">
 <div id="timeline">
  <div id="playhead"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="track"></div>
 <div class="track"></div>
 <div class="track"></div>
 <div class="track"></div>
 <div class="track"></div>
 <div class="track"></div>
 <div class="track"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you trying to make the playhead always on screen? something like using `position:absolute`?

Comment: Is it critical to have the `#playhead` element _inside_ the `#timeline` element?  It might be easier if they are siblings and you can control them separately...

Comment: @NidhinJoseph `position: absolute` gives the same result as `position: relative` - I am mainly trying to work out how to force the height to cover the divs

Comment: @AlexanderNied It can be outside as long as it is inside the `#playlist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want the green bar to always stay on top while you can scroll the tracks, nest all tracks in a div and give it overflow: auto; and have the timeline be positioned, absolute.

```css
#playhead {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 64px;
  position: relative;
  width: 2px;
}
#playlist {
  width: 1024px;
  position: relative;
}
#timeline {
  background-color: green;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.tracks {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
.track {
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div id="playlist">
  <div id="timeline">
    <div id="playhead"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tracks">
    <div class="track"></div>
    <div class="track"></div>
    <div class="track"></div>
    <div class="track"></div>
    <div class="track"></div>
    <div class="track"></div>
    <div class="track"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works very well, but using `position: fixed` cuts off the top of the first track. Would it be possible to avoid cutting into this div?

Comment: @MysteryPancake I haven't used `position: fixed`. I used `position: relative` on timeline and `absolute` on playhead.

Comment: @Ibu Sorry, my mistake - `position: relative` still cuts off the top of the first track though - if there is text in the first `track` div, the text will be visibly cut off. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: It seems changing `position: absolute` to `position: relative` on `#timeline` fixes this issue. Thank you so much for this answer!!

Answer (score 1):

You could set the height of `#playhead` to an extremely high value ( 10000px in my example), and apply `height: 100%;´ and ´overflow-y: hidden;´ to`#playlist`. That way the playhead line will span the whole height (and more), but its vertical extension across the container (`#playlist`) will be cut off.

```css
#playhead {
  background-color: white;
  height: 10000px;
  left: 64px;
  position: relative;
  width: 2px;
}

#playlist {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#timeline {
  background-color: green;
  height: 16px;
}

.track {
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div id="playlist">
  <div id="timeline">
    <div id="playhead"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="track"></div>
  <div class="track"></div>
  <div class="track"></div>
  <div class="track"></div>
  <div class="track"></div>
  <div class="track"></div>
  <div class="track"></div>
</div>
```